# Angular Material md-input-class

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

is there any way I can manipulate the class input of an angular-material md-autocomplete tag?
Something like:

```
<input flex="" type="search" id="search" name="" class="form-control input-form">
```

While I currently have this when I generate my md-autocomplete:

```
<input flex="" type="search" id="search" name="" ng-if="!floatingLabel" autocomplete="off" ng-required="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.isRequired" ng-disabled="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.isDisabled" ng-model="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.scope.searchText" ng-keydown="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.keydown($event)" ng-blur="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.blur()" ng-focus="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.focus()" placeholder="" aria-owns="ul-0" aria-label="" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant="" aria-expanded="false" class="ng-scope ng-valid ng-valid-required flex input-form form-control ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" aria-disabled="false" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but if you just want to add some classes you can probably add a custom directive to manipulate the element. Something along the lines of this (not tested):

```
module.directive('myAutocomplete', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.find('input')[0].classList.add('form-control', 'input-form');
        }
    };
});
```

And us it like this:

```
<md-autocomplete my-autocomplete ....
```